# How to properly setup socket io in MERN app?

Tags: sockets, socket.io, mern

I am new to socket.io. I have basic understanding of how it works, but I am struggling to find proper setup for it within MERN app. If there is any article, or guidance that you can give me, I would appretiate it. I am building social network app, and I need to have live notifications and messages. So I am not sure how to setup socket.io client in react. Should I instanciate it in helper file, like mongoose in express, or is there any other way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
           Install socket.io for server app
```

Install socket.io - client for client app

import socket.io in server page

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server, { cors: { origin: '*' } }) //for omit cors error

const PORT = 2900;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());


io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    console.log("user connected")

    socket.on('valor', ({ id, name, }, callback) => {
        console.log('data::', id, name)

        socket.emit('receiveGreet', { data: 'This message from server' }, (error) => {
            console.log('error::', error)
        })
        callback()
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected')

    })
})


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('api running')
})

server.listen(PORT, console.log(`server running in node on port ${PORT}`));
```

Client side Code May look like this

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket: any;
const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:2900';

const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io(serverUrl);

    socket.on('receiveGreet', (data) => {
      console.log('data::', data);
    });
  }, []);

  return () => {
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.off();
  };
};
```